# React - Optionally wrap an item in a link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that displays a title and some text. I want to optionally wrap the title in a link (the same component is used in more than one place), and would appreciate guidance for the best way to do it. 
My component looks like this:

```
var FeedItem = React.createClass({
  renderRawMarkup: function(text) { ... },
  render: function() {
    var item = this.props.item,
      rawBody = this.renderRawMarkup(item.body);


  return (
    <article className="feed-item">
      <h2 className="feed-item__title">{item.title{</h2>
      <div className="feed-item__body" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={rawBody} >
      </div>
    </article>
  );
});
```

Am I best to create a new component just for the title? Or can I use an if inside the return, e.g.:

```
<h2 className="feed-item__title">
  {if (item.path) { <a href={item.path}> }}
    {item.title}
  {if (item.path) { </a> }}
</h2>
```

I'm a bit of a React novice so apologies if I'm approaching the problem from completely the wrong angle!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `if` statements inside jsx, but you can make use of `ternary expressions`. In your case, you can use:

```
<h2 className="feed-item__title">
  { item.path ? <a href={item.path}>{item.title}</a> : {item.title} }
</h2>
```

This is stated in the official documentation: [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html)

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thank you! So it's just a case of RTFM ;) (I haven't been learning using the official docs but maybe I will from now on..)